# Excel formula that returns every value in a column that is not equal to a specified value

Tags: excel-formula

I have a table of Player Stats that I want to use to check the stats of one player against every other player. `Player` is filled with the player you want to check stats for. `Opponent` is every player that is NOT the player in `Player` and should be determined by a formula. The table is structured as follows:

| Player | Opponent |
| --- | --- |
| Player1 | Player2 |
| Player1 | Player3 |
| Player1 | Player4 |

I then have another table that lists all the players.

| Player |
| --- |
| Player1 |
| Player2 |
| Player3 |
| Player4 |

I need help filling out `Opponent` in the first table. My searching lead me to [this thread](https://superuser.com/questions/430854/extract-values-from-a-range-that-are-missing-from-another), but adapting the array formula solution did not work for some reason (I would also like to avoid array formulas if possible).

I then created a Python pandas script that does what I want and tried to convert it to an Excel formula.

Python:

```
player = 'Player1'

players = ['Player1',
         'Player2',
         'Player3',
         'Player4']

opponents = []
for item in players:
    if item != player:
        opponents.append(item)

StatsTable = pd.DataFrame({'Player':player,
                            'Opponent':opponents})
```

Excel (players are listed in the P column)

```
=IF(P2 <> [@Player], P2)
```

While this Excel formula works, it returns a `FALSE` when `Player` matches. Ideally, I do not want this returned at all (if there are 4 players, there should only be 3 rows. Having a row return `FALSE` means I need to have 4 rows and I do not want that). Is there a method that does what I want it to?

Excel version 16.16.27 for Mac

Comment: Why do you want to avoid array formulas, but tag excel-formulas (it's easy using array formulas). And why - if you have a working solution using Python - are you not using that and ask this question? What is it that you really want? And what Excel version are you using?

Comment: @P.b My reasoning to avoid array formulas and why I want it working in Excel are not relevant to my question. These are my requirements, unless a standard formula is not available. I have updated my question with my Excel version. Please reread the question to understand what I am looking for.

Comment: In newer versions FILTER or TOCOL could do the trick, but your version (Excel 2016) needs INDEX/AGGREGATE, like Spectral Instance answered already.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The old-fashioned way is to use something like `INDEX()` and `AGGREGATE()`, e.g.

```
=INDEX(Players,AGGREGATE(14,4,(Players<>A2)*ROW($1:$4),ROWS(Players)-ROW($A1)))
```

(PLAYERS is the name given to the `M2:M5` range)
[image: Screenshot illustrating suggested formula]

FYI whenever Python in Excel does come to the MAC, the result of your code will be rendered as a (spilled) array formula:

[image: Screenshot illustrating OP's code in Excel]

Comment: Can you explain how the ROW($1:$4) works? If I move my data from rows 1:4 (for example, to rows 2:5) the formula breaks, and merely changing it to ROW($2:$5) doesn't work. However, the following works fine even if I move the data somewhere like I10: 
```=INDEX(Players[Players],AGGREGATE(14,4,(Players[Players]<>I10)*ROW($1:$4),ROWS(Players[Players])-ROW($A1)))```

Why do ROW($1:$4) and ROW($A1) not need to change to reflect the new location of the data?

Comment: @Exquisite_Poupon `ROW($1:$4)` evaluates to `{1;2;3;4}` so it relates to the _size_ of your data, not their _location_. `ROWS(Players)-ROW($A1)` was employed solely to mirror the order of opponents as returned by your Python code - if this order doesn't matter then you can just use `ROW($A1)` in the last part of the formula: it serves to return the 1st large number in the cell where it is entered, the 2nd large number when copied down to the next cell...